# Valoracion de estrellas animado con CSS

Tags: html, css

Hola alguien sabe como puedo darle a mis estrellas el efecto que giren y cambien de color al pasarle el mouse por encima como muestra esta pagina web https://programadorwebvalencia.com/css-valoracion-de-estrellas-animado/
Que propiedades tendría que agregarle a mi css?

```css
    div.valoracion {
      position: relative;
      overflow: hidden;
      display: inline-block;
    }
    
    div.valoracion input {
      position: absolute;
      top: -100px;
    }
    
    div.valoracion label {
      float: right;
      color: #333;
      width: 23px;
      font-size: 25px;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    div.valoracion label:hover,
    div.valoracion label:hover ~ label,
    div.valoracion input:checked ~ label {
      color: #dd4;
    }
```

```html
 <div class="valoracion">
        <input id="radio1" type="radio" name="estrellas" value="5">
        <label for="radio1">★</label>
        <input id="radio2" type="radio" name="estrellas" value="4">
        <label for="radio2">★</label>
        <input id="radio3" type="radio" name="estrellas" value="3">
        <label for="radio3">★</label>
        <input id="radio4" type="radio" name="estrellas" value="2">
        <label for="radio4">★</label>
        <input id="radio5" type="radio" name="estrellas" value="1">
        <label for="radio5">★</label>
     </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
:root{
    --color-inactivo: #5f5050;
    --color-hover: #ffa400;
}

i{
    transition: all 800ms ease-in-out;
}

}
.star-rating input {
    display:none;
}

.star-rating :checked ~ i {
    color:var(--color-hover);
}

i:hover{
    transform: rotate(360deg);

}
  
.star-rating label:hover,
.star-rating label:hover ~ i { 
    color: var(--color-hover);
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a45b9a7436.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

        <div class="star-rating">
                <input type="radio" id="5-stars"  value="5" />
                <label for="radio1" class="star"><i class="fas fa-star"></i></label>
                
                <input type="radio" id="4-stars" name="rating" value="4" />
                <label for="radio2" class="star"><i class="fas fa-star"></i></label>
                
                <input type="radio" id="3-stars" name="rating" value="3" />
                <label for="radio3" class="star"><i class="fas fa-star"></i></label>
                
                <input type="radio" id="2-stars" name="rating" value="2" />
                <label for="radio4" class="star"><i class="fas fa-star"></i></label>
                
                <input type="radio" id="1-star" name="estrellas" value="1" />
                <label for="radio4" class="star"><i class="fas fa-star"></i></label>
        </div>
        
</body>
</html>
```

Las estrellas rotan con este codigo, te recomiendo que para la seleccion del valor utilices javascript

Comment: Ya borre la anterior, gracias

Comment: Gracias :)  Roberto Vargas.

Comment: Fue util la respuesta @isa?

Answer (score 0):

En la pagina que comparte está la explicación, faltan los transform: rotate dentro del :hover , lo que dice su códugo es que al pasar el mouse cambie de color, ni más, también después de eso, debe revisar si el float: right le puede ocasionar problema, intente cambiar a position absolutes no funciona.